# Electron app opening multiple windows or processes in spectron test

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

My electron app works as expected but it keeps on opening new windows when I run spectron test that tests for number of windows opened.

Electron version - v8.0.2 , "spectron": "^10.0.1" . I am not sure how to check exact version of spectron.
I am just running a small demo, below I will give code snippet

**Note: I am running the spectron test pointing to .exe file generated by electron-packager.**

Does Anyone have an idea what is the issue if possible how to solve it?

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {

  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

**index.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
const assert = require('assert');
const path = require('path');
const Application = require('spectron').Application;
const electronPath = require('electron');

const app = new Application({
    path: 'C:/demoElectronApp/winx64/demoelectronapp-win32-x64/demoelectronapp.exe',
  });

  describe('client_settings_app', function () {
    this.timeout(10000);

    beforeEach(() => {
      return app.start();
    });

    it('shows only one initial window', async () => {
      const count = await app.client.getWindowCount();
      return assert.equal(count, 1);
    });
  })
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demoelectronapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "electronpackage": "electron-packager . --out winx64"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
   "electron": "^8.2.2",
    "electron-packager": "^14.2.1",
    "assert": "^2.0.0",
    "mocha": "^7.1.1",
    "spectron": "^10.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: npm ls --depth=0
demoelectronapp@1.0.0 C:\demoCLS\demoElectronApp
+-- assert@2.0.0
+-- electron@8.2.2
+-- electron-packager@14.2.1
+-- mocha@7.1.1
+-- path@0.12.7
`-- spectron@10.0.1

Comment: Above are the npm packages installed

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I was having the same issue. And solved by setting remote debugging port.

```
chromeDriverArgs: ['remote-debugging-port=9222']
```

> Full test code:

```
const Application = require('spectron').Application
const assert = require('assert')
const electronPath = require('electron') // Require Electron from the binaries included in node_modules.
const path = require('path')

describe('Application launch', function () {
    this.timeout(10000)

    beforeEach(function () {
        this.app = new Application({
            // Your electron path can be any binary
            // i.e for OSX an example path could be '/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp'
            // But for the sake of the example we fetch it from our node_modules.
            path: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron' + (process.platform === 'win32' ? '.cmd' : '')),

            // Assuming you have the following directory structure

            //  |__ my project
            //     |__ ...
            //     |__ main.js
            //     |__ package.json
            //     |__ index.html
            //     |__ ...
            //     |__ test
            //        |__ spec.js  <- You are here! ~ Well you should be.

            // The following line tells spectron to look and use the main.js file
            // and the package.json located 1 level above.
            args: [path.join(__dirname, '..')],
            env: {
                ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING: true,
                ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING: true,
                NODE_ENV: 'test'
            },
            waitTimeout: 10e3,
            requireName: 'electronRequire',
            chromeDriverLogPath: '../chromedriverlog.txt',
            chromeDriverArgs: ['remote-debugging-port=9222']
        })
        return this.app.start()
    })

    afterEach(function () {
        if (this.app && this.app.isRunning()) {
            return this.app.stop()
        }
    })

    it('shows an initial window', function () {
        return this.app.client.getWindowCount().then(function (count) {
            assert.equal(count, 1)
            // Please note that getWindowCount() will return 2 if `dev tools` are opened.
            // assert.equal(count, 2)
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, and changed the version of the packages I was working with.
This page has the version map:
https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#version-map

It seems like this isn't your problem byt may help others.

Comment: Perhaps it didn't help the OP but it solved the multiple windows issue when using Spectron for me. Not sure why it has downvotes, the answer even states that it won't fix the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY found a way to fix this that worked for me.  I found it in a comment by @wburgess-invision on this gitHub thread here:  https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron/issues/60

1. Navigate to node_modules -> spectron -> lib -> launcher.js
2. after the line "const args = appArgs.concat(chromeArgs);" add a new line and copy and paste this: args.splice(args.indexOf('--enable-logging'), 1)
3. npm run build

To quote the thread: "I noticed that it was happening because of the --enable-logging parameter being passed in. So I made a modified version of launcher.js which purposely didn't include --enable-logging and it worked fine for us. I couldn't find where the spectron launcher was managing to pick up the --enable-logging flag from as I thought a better solution would have been just not providing it to launcher.js in the first place but I couldn't find out so I just went with the solution that worked for now. My assumption was that the --enable-logging flag was being picked up somewhere inside of webdriverio when the client is initialized and thus calls launcher.bat but I couldn't find out where."